# Using the gerund two times in a row

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds

When you have this construct:

> . . . is a key factor in the **making** and **controlling** of the water.

Should you leave only the last verb in the gerund:

> . . . is a key factor in the **make** and **controlling** of the water.

Comment: The verb tense I am using is the _present participle_ or the _gerund_? I would say it is the _present participle_.

Comment: It's the gerund.  You can tell because *making* and *controlling* are functioning as nouns.

Comment: Alternative _to make and control_ where both words again have the same tense

Comment: At least you have a conjunction between the two gerunds. I have experienced sentences in which two gerunds occur in a row with nothing between them. Those sentences, while clear in meaning feel so incredibly unnatural and awkward. (I wish I could think of an example now…)

Comment: @Synetech inc. Please do. Now I'm curious. :)

Comment: @John Assymptoth, *He was considering running for office.* *She was avoiding telling him.* *I ended up stopping watching it.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to say "making and controlling".

What you have there is a **parallel structure**.  A parallel structure is basically when you condense multiple sentences varying in only one item down to a single sentence with a list of the varied items:

> I entered the marathon.  I entered the decathlon.  I entered the pole vault.

becomes

> I entered the marathon, decathlon, and pole vault.

When you form a parallel structure, all the elements in the parallel MUST be in the same grammatical form: all nouns, all gerunds, all infinitive verbs, all prepositional phrases, etc.  No mixing and matching is allowed.

Answer (score 6):

No; the first version is correct.