# Which tense should I use in this situation?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, progressive-aspect, present-participles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the gerund two times in a row](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14327/using-the-gerund-two-times-in-a-row)

Here is the sentence:

> Just as on smoking, voices now come from many quarters (**insisting**
>   or **insist**) that the science about global warming is incomplete,
>   that it's Ok to keep pouring fumes into the air until we know for
>   sure.

Which is correct in the parentheses above, **insisting** or **insist**? Which role does it play here, attribute or some thing else? And could you help me analyze the grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form of the verb there in your sentence is ***insisting***:

> Just as on smoking, voices now come from many quarters insisting that the science about global warming is incomplete . . .

What’s going on here is that English often uses the ***‑ing*** form of a verb along with a verb of motion:

- Peter *went running* all the way home.
- Paula *came in crying*.
- Then they *came back begging* for more money.
- That rascal *goes around complaining* about everything.
- The rescued nuns *arrived singing* praises of thanksgiving in full voice.

How you want to analyze that is up to you.  You could say it is an adverbial verbal phrase that attaches to the motion verb.  You could also say it is creating a sort of progressive tense, like ***am thinking*** does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I am still in a haze.If I remove the part `now come from many quarters`，then it would become `Just as on smoking, voices (insisting or insist) that the science about global warming is incomplete` ,here `voices insist that ...` is just the proper form,in my opinion.And this is where I am stucked.

Comment: @paradox2 If you remove the finite verb *come*, then you need one for your sentence, so would need to change *insisting* to *insist* to carry that weight.

Comment: Do you mean that `voices now insist that the science about global warming is incomplete ` is not a complelte setence?But it just looks right.

Comment: More question,is it correct to say `voices now coming from many quarters insist that...`?

Comment: @paradox2 Yes, that’ll do.

Answer (score 2):

**Insisting** makes more sense here.

> Just as on smoking, voices now come from many quarters **insisting** that the science about global warming is incomplete, that it's Ok to keep pouring fumes into the air until we know for sure.

The reason why the *progressive* makes more sense here is because it's attached to the verb *come*. If you remove that part then there is no verb of motion and the simple present form of the verb makes more sense.

> Just as on smoking, voices **insist** that the science about global warming is incomplete, that it's Ok to keep pouring fumes into the air until we know for sure.

Comment: Isn't `come from many quarters` works as attribute of `voices`?Why it would have influence on `insist`?

Comment: If you remove **from many quarters** it becomes: **voices now come insisting...*** As you can see **come** and **insisting** are closely connected. Now, if you remove **come** it reads: **voices now *insisting**, which is wrong and hence should be replaced with **insist**.